# Scope issue with ng-table tutorial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to implement ng-table and am following the basic steps outlined here: http://ng-table.com/#/

I'm able to get the table headers to display correctly (Name / Age with filters) however there is no data displaying.

A console log of "data" returns the appropriate information but it won't display in the table.  I suspect I have a scoping issue as renaming variables allowed me to pull in the data but broke the sorting functionality which from reviewing other SO questions I understand to be because $data is required for the static data to sort.

The HTML is as follows:

```
    <div id="manager-dashboard-alerts-page">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="title">
            <h1></h1>
            <h4></h4>
        </div>
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the JS is as follows:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
.module('roomchoice.manager-dashboard.alerts', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngTable'
])

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('manager.alerts', {
    url: '/alerts',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'AlertsController',
        controllerAs: 'alerts',
        templateUrl: 'manager-dashboard/alerts/alerts.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  });
})

.controller('AlertsController', AlertsController);

function AlertsController($scope, Restangular, NgTableParams) {
  var vm = this;
  var self = this;
  var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/];
  self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
```

Comment: You are using self.tableParams in your controller in your view vm.tableParams. I do not understand why you have self and this, for any particular reason?

Comment: The vm was pre-existing, I put the self in just in case I was missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `controllerAs: 'alerts'`, but in your HTML you are referring to `vm.tableParams`.

Change it to:

```
<table ng-table="alerts.tableParams" ...
```

*Also make sure you are using the correct version of `ngTable`, the demo uses https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js*

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/z2SlqTl3BX5fXmh5orzV?p=preview